# How to overrides testCaseProperties like projectProperties or testSuiteProperties in pom.xml file?

Tags: maven, soapui

I want to run soapui with Maven, but has problem here and can't find any solution on the internet, want to know: How to overrides **testCaseProperties** just like projectProperties or testSuiteProperties in pom.xml file?

**Reference**: https://github.com/redfish4ktc/maven-soapui-extension-plugin/wiki/Tips

Screenshots as here:
[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ACuo.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Maven plugin you link to clearly doesn't support that. Then I believe you are limited to the options given by the command line interface.

https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html

From that, my guess would be that you can't. Not by only using this.

However, you may consider creating some sort of setup script for your TestSuite, that reads a project property, which can be set from the commandline. That one property may then be path and name for some sort of input file, and the script can then read it, and import any setting you have specified within to set any variables you may wish.